# How do I get x.something.com rather than something.com/x?

Tags: web, dns

I was just wondering how to design a website so you can have the addresses for the different pages as I indicated in the title.

So how do you get x.something.com rather than something.com/x?

Comment: You configure the hostname in your DNS (the specifics of which depend on your DNS server) and (usually) a virtual name host in your HTTP server (the specifics of which depend on which HTTP server you are using).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a DNS entry with value of * and url as same as the www url or blank field's url(both which are in fact same and should be)

Then add these lines to your .htaccess file at the root www folder

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^x.something.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.something.com/x [R,L]
```

Remember that x is your subdomain and something.com is your domain and besure you have the .htaccess file in the root www folder.

For more just comment...

Thanks